# How to put "i' in cells (range). Excel

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

In code below I have 2 problems:

1) In range ws['B3:B7'] I have to write rule **until the end of column/row** or **until empty cell** ws['B3:??']

2) In while loop I have to put **'i'** in cells, and also to have to write rule **until the end of column/row**  or **until empty cell** ws['D3:??']

 My code shows error ->  *builtins.AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'value'* in line ws['D3:D7'] = i


 I don't understand why range considers as a tuple and how to solve this error?

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

wb = load_workbook('Test.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

values = [row[0].value for row in ws['B3:B7']]
a = datetime.datetime.date(min(values))
b = datetime.datetime.date(max(values))

i = a

while i <= b:
    ws['D3:D7'] = i
    i = i + relativedelta(months = 1)


wb.save('Test2.xlsx')
```

Comment: You'll want to add an example of your test file and what you want the output to look like.

Comment: Example: Period (01.01.2017 to 31.12.2017). 01.01.2017 -> **A1**, 01.02.2017 -> **B1** and etc.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53617788/edit) instead of adding info in comments